# Modifying List of String in scala

Tags: scala

I have input file i would like to read a scala stream and then modify each record and then output the file.

My input is as follows -

```
Name,id,phone-number
abc,1,234567
dcf,2,345334
```

I want to change the above input as follows -

```
Name,id,phone-number
    testabc,test1,test234567
    testdcf,test2,test345334
```

I am trying to read a file as scala stream as follows:

```
val inputList = Source.fromFile("/test.csv")("ISO-8859-1").getLines
```

after the above step i get Iterator[String]

```
val newList = inputList.map{line => 
              line.split(',').map{s =>
                "test" + s
              }.mkString (",")
          }.toList
```

but the new list is empty. 
I am not sure if i can define an empty list and empty array and then append the modified record to the list.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you actually managing to read the file?

Comment: i am able to read the file. but i am stuck with modifying the data.the following code - val newList = inputList.map{line => 
              line.split(',').map{s =>
                println("test" + s)
              }
          }

Comment: missing return in the first map?

Comment: @Dimitri Why does he need return?

Comment: Ahh sorry, it's scala. You are right you don't need a return. Make sure that you are actually reading the file and the file is not empty

Comment: The file is not empty i see the content of the file when println on inputList.

Comment: An iterator can only be used once. Println "uses" it. Map it immediately and it should work.

Comment: yes, thats correct. this was the problem. as soon as removed the inputlist.println() from the code. It worked. Thanks! I should change the iterator to list.

Comment: Accidentally consuming an iterator is a thing. An example here with code might be useful, or maybe there's a duplicate question. A linter for that would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to transform the iterator into a stream

```
val l = Source.fromFile("test.csv")
    .getLines()
    .toStream
    .tail
    .map { row =>
      row.split(',')
        .map { col =>
         s"test$col"
        }.mkString (",")
     }

  l.foreach(println)
```

> testabc,test1,test234567
>
> testdcf,test2,test345334

Answer (score 1):

Here's a similar approach that returns a `List[Array[String]]`. You can use `mkString`, `toString`, or similar if you want a `String` returned.

```
scala> scala.io.Source.fromFile("data.txt")
  .getLines.drop(1)
  .map(l => l.split(",").map(x => "test" + x)).toList

res3: List[Array[String]] = List(
  Array(testabc, test1, test234567), 
  Array(testdcf, test2, test345334)
)
```